# PipeLine.InvokeAsync not working

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to call powershell file from c# code asynchronously like fire and forget. I tried using Powershell.BeginInvoke but it does not invokes the file until I call EndInvoke. Anyway, I tried pipeline.InvokeAsync method but still am not able to invoke the script.It works when I just call Invoke method. Below is the code I tried

```
using(  PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
        { 
Pipeline pipe = shell.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipe.Commands.AddScript("d:\\AddContentTest.ps1"); 
pipe.InvokeAsync(); 
}
```

Any help is much appreciated...............

Comment: Why do you need to invoke it asynchronously?

Comment: I have asp.net app from where I m calling a script which does a remote job.Basically, I am doing some background task by calling PS Script and for which I don't want my app to wait.I know I can do this by calling ThreadPool but was looking for any other better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `InvokeAsync` without `await`ing it. The method returns immediately,  and the PowerShell will dispose since you're exiting the `using` scope.

Try this:

```
public async Task InvokePowerShellAsync()
{ 
    using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
    { 
         Pipeline pipe = shell.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
         pipe.Commands.AddScript("d:\\AddContentTest.ps1"); 

         await pipe.InvokeAsync(); 
    }
}
```

**Edit**

To complete the answer, and to your comment, you can use a background thread although I dont recommend that approach:

```
public void InvokePowerShellAsync()
{ 
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        using (PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create())
        { 
            Pipeline pipe = shell.Runspace.CreatePipeline();
            pipe.Commands.AddScript("d:\\AddContentTest.ps1");

            pipe.Invoke();
        }        
    }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If I use await then it is going to wait for script to complete.it won't be fire and forget.  Script am trying to run now is small and hence it is getting completed quickly but actual script which I will use will run for longer time like around 2 mins and i will get asp.net timeout error if I follow this approach. I guess I have to go with ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem but if you have any other solution which will address my problem.Please let me know.......Thanks again....

Comment: using `await` isn't like waiting on your `Task`. Control will yield back to the caller. If you want to use it with a backgroubd thread use the `Task Parallel Library`

Comment: I have .net 4.0 framework so Task.Run won't work for me but I got fair idea now how I can implement my solution.I never worked much with Task parallel library but I think I will give it try.Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use `Task.Factory.Startnew` instead

Comment: Anyone got "Cannot await 'void' when trying to use await pipeline.InvokeAsync()? (Using .Net Core)

Answer (score 0):

this is an unmanaged port. Awaiting the [Pipeline.InvokeAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.pipeline.invokeasync?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) will not work.

MS documentation will do better than me:

> 1. Results are returned through the Output reader. 2) When pipeline is
>    invoked using InvokeAsync, **invocation doesn't finish until Input to
>    pipeline is closed**. Caller of InvokeAsync must close the input pipe
>    after all input has been written to input pipe. Input pipe is closed
>    by calling Pipeline.Input.Close();

Instead, you need to call the **Pipeline.Input.Close()** prior to and *must not await* the **InvokeAsync**